# htaccess redirect if a specific folder doesnt exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am using this in the root htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 
RewriteRule .* index.php?p=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This rewrites http://example.com/notexistsfolder successfully

But i want also to redirect http://example.com/user/notexistsfolder to http://example.com/notexistsfolder

What code should i add to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that you need in `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ $1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule (?!^user/)^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```